# Where does Java File instance store?

Tags: java, file

I have a question regarding to the Java File class. When I create a File instance, for example,

```
File aFile = new File(path);
```

Where does the instance aFile store in the computer? Or it stores in JVM? I mean is there a temp file stored in the local disk?

If I have an InputStream instance, and write it to a file by using OutputSteam, for example

```
  File aFile = new File("test.txt");

  OutputStream anOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(aFile);

  byte aBuffer[] = new byte[1024];

  while( ( iLength = anInputStream.read( aBuffer ) ) > 0)
  {
    anOutputStream.write( aBuffer, 0, iLength);
  }
```

Now where does the file test.txt store?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `File` object isn't a real file at all - it's really just a filename/location, and methods which hook into the file system to check whether or not the file really exists etc. There's no *content* directly associated with the `File` instance - it's not like it's a virtual in-memory file, for example. The instance itself is just an object in memory like any other object.

Creating a `File` instance on its own does *nothing* to the file system.

When you create a `FileOutputStream`, however, that *does* affect whatever file system you're writing to. The `File` instance is relatively irrelevant though - you'd get the same effect from:

```
OutputStream anOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

It will write the file where you specify it with path arguement.

In your case, it will write it in the directory where you run your java class.

If you specify /test/myproject/myfile.txt

it will go in /test/myproject/myfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide a path, it is in the current directory (ie: the directory where java.exe is executed from.) If you provide a full path, it is stored there.

Regardless, it is always stored in the filesystem, not in JVM memory.